# NSMutableDictionary isn't stick around long enough

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management

Sorry, beginner here . . .

So I create an NSMutableDictionary in my app delegate when the application launches, and then later pass it on to a view controller, as it contains options for the VC like a background image, a url I want to parse, etc.

Anyway, i wrote a custom init method for the VC, initWithOptions, where I pass the dictionary on. I'm trying to use this dictionary later on in other methods - so I created a NSMutableDictionary property for my VC and am trying to store the passed options dictionary there. However, when I go to get the contents of that property in later methods, it returns null. If i access it from the init method, it works. heres some sample code:

```
-(id)initWithOptions:(NSMutableDictionary *)options {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    self.optionsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:options];
    NSLog(@"dictionary in init method %@",self.optionsDict);
```

that NSLog logs the contents of the dictionary, and it looks like its working. then later when I do this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{    
     SDJConnection *connection = [[SDJConnection alloc]init];
    self.dataArray = [connection getEventInfoWithURL:[self.optionsDict objectForKey:@"urlkey"]];
    NSLog(@"dictionary in connection contains: %@", [self.optionsDict objectForKey:@"urlkey"]);
    [_tableView reloadData];
```

the dictionary returns null. Ive tried adjusting the property attributes, and it didn't work with either strong or retain. Any ideas??

THANKS!!

Comment: sorry that code at the bottom is a little off - replace the "dict" with self.optionsDict

Comment: You can do it yourself editing your question :)

Comment: no i mean it still doesn't work even with that correction

Comment: Without that correction it doesn't make much sense since you are accessing different variables...

Comment: Figured it out: I moved that code from viewDidLoad to ViewDidAppear and now its working fine. I guess for some reason viewDidLoad was being called before the options dictionary was set? interesting.

Comment: You can use breakpoints in init, viewWillLoad/viewDidLoad, and viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear to see exactly when they execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to me sometimes.  You forgot to call `[super viewDidLoad]` so your properties will not be created.  Your viewDidLoad will take the place of UIViewController's viewDidLoad.